# how to add columns with 'filled data' after filling missing values in pandas or python using different techniques?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

How to add columns with 'filled data' *after filling missing values* in pandas or python, using different or several techniques like various statistical techniques or machine learning techniques.

What I want to do is that, after filling the data let's say with mean, median or standard deviation values or with other machine learning algos, like KNN or XGBoost or some other technique, then I want to add or append those or that particular column(s) at the end of the csv or excel file but not below the actual data, I mean towards the right-end side of the file.

For instance, I've filled the missing data of a particular column using statistical techniques and other ML techniques then I want to add those 'filled values' along with the original values in a new column having it's actual name with underscore and the technique with which the data is filled for that particular feature and add it at the end of the data to the right side of the data. Example, the column or feature is 'phone' then at the right-end side after filling missing values it must show the whole original or actual values plus the values calculated by statistical means or ML means with column name like "phone_Mean" or "phone_interpolation" or 'phone_KNN' or 'phone_XGBoost' like that.

What I've done so far ?
I've applied the ways from the pandas documentation page and stackoverflow as well, the ones which are generally high enlisted and are in top 7/10 links on google or duckduckgo search engines, but all went in vain.

I'm really facing this issue from last few days due to which I'm crippled at convincing my client. So, it will be great help if you can assist me with some code example using pandas or core python code to support your answer.

Here's the snippet of the dataset. Let's say I'm applying techniques on a feature/column named 'phone':

[image]

Comment: show an example of your dataframe and your dataframe expected....I think your a re lookign for `pandas.concat` with axis=1.....

Comment: I've added the snippet of the dataset and I did have applied pd.concat or pd.join or even like 'a + b' but no results.

Please look into it now and let me know how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is by making use of pandas like:-

df_01["phone_mean"] = df_01["phone"].fillna().mean()